# Dock Windows 7 gadgets against screen edge

Tags: windows-7, sidebar, desktop-gadget

I've got four gadgets on my Windows 7 desktop. I want them to dock against the edge of the screen, such that maximized windows don't cover them (the "Always On Top" option doesn't meet my needs).

Is there a setting or tool which will allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mydigitallife](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/12/30/workaround-to-run-windows-vista-bar-style-sidebar-in-windows-7/) has this info:

> ### Workaround to Run Windows Vista Bar Style Sidebar in Windows 7
>
> 1. Close all gadgets on desktop.
> 2. Take ownership and grant full control permissions for Administrators user group of the following files located in C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar folder:
>
>    settings.ini
>         sidebar.exe
>
>    And inside the en-US Folder:
>
>    ```
>    sbdrop.dll.mui  
>    Sidebar.exe.mui
>    ```
> 3. Rename to backup the 4 files listed above.
> 4. Download [Win7-Sidebar-Fix.zip](http://www.ziddu.com/download/3042059/Win7-Sidebar-Fix.zip.html).
> 5. Extract and copy the contents of the ZIP file to their corresponding folders in C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar folder, overwrite and replace existing files if applicable.
> 6. Re-add gadgets to desktop.